# What does Boost Converter With 2-A Switch mean?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, boost

I am new to boost converter technology. All i want to know is what does switch current indicate.

Comment: The answer is in the datasheet for your part.  Even if we wanted to read the datasheet for you, we are unable to do it, because we don't even know what part are you talking about.

Comment: It indicates how much current the switch subcircuit can handle without blowing up.

Comment: Based on your answer, if the current is 2.1A, the switch blows up.

Comment: I want to use TPS61200 and it is rated for 1.3A current. Do i have to supply this current? i assume this switch is internal to the IC, and i can only supply input voltage and take ouput voltage from predefined pins. But i am not getting the points of switch current. Thanks

Comment: @GregoryKornblum: For a certain definition of "blows up", yes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no research effort was shown.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A boost converter converts a lower voltage to a higher voltage.  An ideal boost converter has 100% efficiency, so power out = power in.

The switch has to handle the input current, so for (example) a 10V 1A output from a 5V input means the output power is 10W, the input power is 10W, so the input current is 2A average (plus half the inductor ripple current peak).

So to supply an output current of X Amps you need Vout/Vin*X + Iripple/2 as a switch current limit in the IDEAL case.  Since boost converters are not 100% efficient, you need to estimate the efficiency and divide by that in order to get the actual required switch current limit.

So to answer your question, you don't have to supply the 1.3A unless your output power requires it.